# Configuring Multiple Nodejs Apps to nginx conf

Tags: node.js, nginx, configuration

How to configure multiple virtual hosted nodejs apps on same machine with different port to nginx conf? I tried location tag with different proxy_pass but it throws no css js error on one location and on another it’s get method error..

Please help me out. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simple like this for instance:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name yourdomain.com;

   location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   }
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name yourotherdomain.com;

   location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
   }
}
```